# Simple Algebra in Excel Formula

Tags: excel, algorithm, excel-formula

I am trying to have Excel solve "X" for me.

(X-100)/X=60% or (X-100)/X=.6

The "100" data is the cell I will be changing as needed. Basically I am looking to input a number to replace "100" and be given the number that would equate to 60% GP of that number. I hope that makes sense.

Thank you

[image]

Comment: Do you want a table that computes Sale for various Cost that will result in a fixed GP of 60%?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(X-100)/X=60% gets you X = 100 / 0.4.
You can just use the equation X = Cost / 0.4 and replace Cost with whatever number you need.

Comment: I certainly was overthinking that. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If the data and various cost values are like below,

[image]

Enter the below formula in cell `A2` and drag down,

```
=B2/0.4
```

Comment: I certainly was overthinking that. Thank you!

Comment: @Joe Great!! Please mark my answer as correct if you found this helpfull